# ACM programming competition - Python solution

Tags: python

I've been staring at an ACM programming problem for days and can't figure out why my  solution in Python isn't accepted. It fails on "Test 28" and the computer does not tell you what the input for "Test 28" looks like. I left the question in the original wording--it is from some ACM website in Russia or China. This is the question:

*A child receives a test consisting of multiple-choice questions as homework. A multiple-choice question consists of four choices: A, B, C and D. Each choice has a description and the child is asked to choose the correct answer.*

*The child did not read his book beforehand and does not know the answer. Fortunately, he has devised a clever strategy. The child will follow this algorithm:*

*1. If there is some choice whose description at least twice shorter than all other descriptions, or at least twice longer than all other descriptions, then the child thinks the choice is great.*

*2. If there is exactly one great choice then the child chooses it. Otherwise the child chooses C (the child think it is the luckiest choice).*

*You are given a multiple-choice question, can you predict the child's choice?*

Input:
The first line starts with "A." (without quotes), then followed by the description of choice A. The next three lines contain the descriptions of the other choices in the same format. They are given in the order B, C, D. Please note that the description goes after prefix "X.", so the prefix must not be counted in description's length.

Each description is non-empty and consists of at most 100 characters. Each character can be either uppercase English letter or lowercase English letter, or "_".

Output:
Print a single line with the child's choice: "A", "B", "C" or "D" (without quotes).

Sample Input:

```
Input
A.VFleaKing_is_the_author_of_this_problem
B.Picks_is_the_author_of_this_problem
C.Picking_is_the_author_of_this_problem
D.Ftiasch_is_cute

Output
D

Input
A.ab
B.abcde
C.ab
D.abc

Output
C

Input
A.c
B.cc
C.c
D.c

Output
B
```

My solution is here: http://ideone.com/FzXvvc

Comment: @poke: no, if you run the code with the given test inputs you will get other alphabetical letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to deal with the solution in which there is more than one good solution (`larger = 3` *and* `smaller = 3`).  In your case, `minkey` will be returned, not `c`.  The problem requires `c` in that case.

Try:

```
if larger == 3:
    if smaller == 3:
        return "C"
    else:
        return minkey
elif smaller == 3:
    return maxkey
else:
    return "C"
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right...I think I am turning this program into spaghetti code. How would you write the algorithm for the solution?

Comment: Answer edited to suggest a solution.  You will want to test it first.

Comment: They finally accepted the solution. Thanks!!